# Resources to learn computational chemistry?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I am interested in learning computational chemistry to explore the possibility of postgraduate work in quantum/theoretical chemistry and would like to attempt self-studying.  I know the basics of quantum mechanics on par with a p.chem course and have an understanding of linear algebra and differential equations.  Are there any other resources that would help me in learning?

As far as I know, there is no software suited for learning computational chemistry on a desktop PC.  But would there be anything similar that would assist in my learning?

Also I am lacking in the programming side of things, would that be a significant barrier to my learning, especially when using computational software in the future?

Comment: Here is a good place to go, http://molecularmodelingbasics.blogspot.co.uk/ and the software can be obtained here http://www.msg.ameslab.gov/gamess/ then there are youtube tutorials